# Power Supply with Supercapacitor

Tags: power-supply, power, supercapacitor

[image]

You were tasked to designed a power supply unit which could change its voltage from 0 V to 5 V DC and its
current to 0 A to 2 A. The maximum internal resistance of the unit is 500 Ω. At the same time, it could also
store energy on a double layer capacitor or what we call a “supercapacitor”. Is the design possible? What is
the maximum power the design could give? If the supply is cut off what required size of the supercapacitor
is needed so that the unit could continue supply electrical energy for 2 minutes with a minimum functioning
voltage of 5 V at 2 A. Draw the equivalent block and circuit diagram of the power supply unit

I understand that I need a battery for this, and that supercapacitor can replace the battery. But I can't get it started as I am having a hard time figuring out the equivalent diagram. It would be easy to analyze if there is. Please help. I connected the power supply in parallel with capacitor so this works by charging the bank and the bank will discharge when fully charged. but i am asked to design a circuit where the supply is cut off but still supplying energy.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but this is obviously a homework question so we're not going to do it for you. There's a schematic editor button on the editor toolbar. Draw the schematic as best you can and explain where you're stuck. Put all the details _in your question_ and not in the comments.

Comment: Hello. already edited it

Comment: Your sketch shows a battery instead of a variable power source so that's not going to work. Your question specifies an internal resistance of 500 Ω. I don't see it in your sketch. The question lists "a double layer capacitor" (whatever that is) but your sketch shows two capacitors. If the supply is to be cut you should add a switch. Use the schematic editor or explain why you can't if using a mobile device.

Comment: "double layer capacitor" is a supercapacitor. I have read somewhere that a supercapacitor can replace the battery, but could not understand the rest of the article says. So I was assuming that my supercapacitor could be my battery for 5V at 2A for 2 minutes.

Comment: I think the question is simply: What capacitance and (charging) voltage is required for a capacitor to be at 5V after discharging with 2A for 120 seconds. The energy stored in a capacitor is E = 1/2*C*U², you should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Yes. And we need to provide values for capacitance and voltage which is I am not sure if solvable or what.

Comment: @transistor If we add a switch, will it still supply energy when the supply is cut off? I have read that we can store energy in a capacitor.

Comment: The question says "if the supply is cut off" so if your circuit can't supply energy then you won't be able to complete the question. "_I have read that we can store energy in a capacitor._" You're going to need some facts and formulas to complete this question. I'm trying to understand why you are being asked this question when you seem to be lacking in understanding of the theory to answer it.

Comment: Surely we are. That's why I am trying to seek for help. The Prof only gave us a formula which is E = 1/2*C*V^2, the rest is ours. This is designing our own circuit so it should be different from my classmates.

Comment: Puzzled. - "Is the design possible?" The fact that this is even asked makes me suspicious that the answer is supposed to be 'No' and you should then give mathematical reasons. But in fact the answer is clearly 'Yes' since we can just go out and buy one with that spec!

Comment: Are you from TIP?
The Students Outcome (A) exam?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a homework question, I'm not going to give you the answer. But here are some hints for the concepts you need to research to solve the problem.

> a power supply unit which could change its voltage from 0 V to 5 V DC and its current to 0 A to 2 A.

I read this to mean a variable power supply. The input might come from a battery, but then you need to convert the voltage somehow. You might do this with an *adjustable linear regulator*, or a *switch mode power supply*.

> The maximum internal resistance of the unit is 500 Ω.

This probably means the *Thévenin equivalent resistance*. Read datasheets.

> At the same time, it could also store energy on a double layer capacitor or what we call a “supercapacitor”. Is the design possible? What is the maximum power the design could give?

These might be trick questions. After researching the other things you should be able to reason about the circuit to answer them.

> If the supply is cut off what required size of the supercapacitor is needed so that the unit could continue supply electrical energy for 2 minutes with a minimum functioning voltage of 5 V at 2 A.

This problem probably involves the fundamental equation that defines *capacitance*:

$$ I(t) = C \frac{\mathrm{d}V(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} $$